# consolidating javascript script tags into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

i am attempting to use [wavesurfer.js](http://wavesurfer.js) and currently have the following:

```
   'use strict'
    <!-- wavesurfer.js -->
    <script src="src/wavesurfer.js"></script>
    <script src="src/util.js"></script>
    <script src="src/webaudio.js"></script>
    <script src="src/mediaelement.js"></script>
    <script src="src/drawer.js"></script>
    <script src="src/drawer.canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugin/wavesurfer.regions.js"></script>
    var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
```

and this works fine.

i need to consolidate all of these into one , and use something like:

```
<script src="myWavesurfer.js"></script>
var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
```

i have tried the following:

```
var jScripts2Call =
[ '/src/wavesurfer.js',
  '/src/util.js',
  '/src/webaudio.js',
  '/src/mediaelement.js',
  '/src/drawer.js',
  '/src/drawer.canvas.js',
  '/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.js'];
// load all the jScripts
for ( var i=0; i < jScripts2Call.length; i++ )  {
    var script    = document.createElement('script');
    script.src    = jScripts2Call[i];
    script.type   = 'text/javascript';
    script.async  = false;
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    scripts.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scripts);
};
var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
```

but these scripts dont "execute" before i call Object.create(WaveSurfer), only afterwards.  i have tried using jquery:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
})
```

and i have also tried the jQuery(dot)getScript() which only seems to load the first script.  i had a little better luck using jQuery(dot)ajax(), but again i could not get the scripts to load and execute before the Object.create(WaveSurfer) call.

it appears that [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) might be the way to go, but i was hoping for something much simpler.

as always, any and all help is very appreciated.  ideas?

Comment: Try adding check for object or function defined within each loaded file after each file loads , before proceeding to next file at `jScripts2Call` ; call `var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);` after all files loaded ?

Comment: `gulp-concat` is very easy, what part of it is complex??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the load event and not the ready event. Ready triggers when all the html tags themselves have finished loading, not when the other files finish. Using jquery, you could do something like this:

```
$( window ).load( function() {
  var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
})
```

Or using regular js (as you don't really need jquery for this):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
}
```

Comment: wow!  i have been beating my head against the wall for a couple of days on this, and you solved it near instantly.   THANK YOU!